# Most recent employee position in date period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to accomplish 2 things from the following data:

| EMPLOYEEID | POSITION | DATEFROM | DATETO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0760891 | Associate Director | 2014-10-28 00:00:00.000 | 2018-05-11 00:00:00.000 |
| 0760891 | Executive Director | 2018-05-14 00:00:00.000 | NULL |
| 1048137 | Assistant Director | 2019-07-08 00:00:00.000 | 2021-07-12 00:00:00.000 |
| 1048137 | Coordinator | 2021-07-13 00:00:00.000 | NULL |

We use an evaluation year that runs from May to April (5/1 - 4/30). So, for each EMPLOYEEID, I need output that looks like this:

| EMPLOYEEID | Position | Evaluation Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0760891 | Associate Director | 2015 |
| 0760891 | Associate Director | 2016 |
| 0760891 | Associate Director | 2017 |
| 0760891 | Associate Director | 2018 |
| 0760891 | Associate Director | 2019 |
| 0760891 | Executive Director | 2020 |
| 0760891 | Executive Director | 2021 |
| 0760891 | Executive Director | 2022 |
| 1048137 | Assistant Director | 2020 |
| 1048137 | Assistant Director | 2021 |
| 1048137 | Assistant Director | 2022 |

First requirement: "Fill in" a Position and Evaluation Year row, per EMPLOYEEID, for any evaluation years between DATEFROM and DATETO.

Second requirement: Return only the *last* active position per EMPLOYEEID and Evaluation Year in cases where the DATETO and DATEFROM values for two positions overlap within an evaluation year.

The issue I'm having is that I can't seem to get the most recent (last) position in situations where -- e.g. in the case of EMPLOYEEID 1048137 here -- there are two positions "active" in the same evaluation year (either begins or ends in the evaluation year). That employee's Evaluation Year 2022 value should be Coordinator, not Assistant Director, but the code I've written is producing the output pictured in the second table above. It seems like I should be able to employ ROW_NUMBER to get what I need, but I'm struggling trying to implement it correctly (if, in fact, I need to implement it at all for this issue).

SQL Server 2014.

Thanks so much for your kind attention.

Comment: OUTER JOIN a year table/cte.

Comment: Why is `0760891` a `Associate Director` in `2019` when they became one on `2018-05-14 00:00:00.000`? When your 2019 year started (`2019-05-01`) they had been an `Executive Director` for *almost* a full year.

Comment: Sorry, @Larnu, yes, our evaluation year works like a fiscal year that begins on July 1. So July 1 2021 is fiscal year 2022. For our evaluation year, May 1 2021 is the first day of evaluation year 2022. 0760891 was an Executive Director for only two weeks in evaluation year 2022, but *that's* the value I want to display in my final result set, *not* the Associate Director position (same issue as 1048137).

Comment: *"We use an evaluation year that runs from May to April (5/1 - 4/30)."* Vs *"our evaluation year works like a fiscal year that begins on July 1."* These statements conflict.

Comment: That also doesn't explain why the person has the other title in 2019 when they never do

Comment: I mean Executive Director in evaluation year 2019, not 2022. My bad, @Larnu.

Comment: @Larnu the previous title ends 11 days into evaluation year 2019. Also, I was only mentioning the fiscal year as an example of adjusted year values based on arbitrary month/day boundaries. Sorry for that confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM yourtable a
LEFT JOIN yourtable b
ON a.EMPLOYEEID = b.EMPLOYEEID and a.DATETO > b.DATETO
WHERE b.EMPLOYEEID IS NULL
```

Explanation: You search the `a` records where does not exist such a `b` record that has the same `EMPLOYEEID` and has a later `DATEFROM`.